# Is mandatory extend the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class when ProblemDetail is applied?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Since `Spring Framework` **6** exists available the [ProblemDetail](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.java) class.

Through some tutorials I wrote the following code:

```
//Ignore the two latest Parameters
@ExceptionHandler({CienciaNotFoundException.class})
ProblemDetail handlerMappingFor404(Exception ex, WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest req) {
    ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    problemDetail.setTitle("Resource requested does not exist");
    problemDetail.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
    problemDetail.setProperty("dateTime", DateTimeUtils.currentDateTime());
    return problemDetail;
}
```

And through `curl`, for the next command:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777 \
     -v -H "Accept: application/json" | jq .
```

is confirmed that it returns:

```
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Resource requested does not exist",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "No existe Ciencia con 'id' 777",
  "instance": "/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777",
  "dateTime": "2023-07-23 21:21:49"
}
```

The output works as expected

The reason of this: consider the two following scenarios as follows:

(A) With `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class WebRestControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    //Ignore the two latest Parameters
    @ExceptionHandler({CienciaNotFoundException.class})
    ProblemDetail handlerMappingFor404(Exception ex, WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest req) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        problemDetail.setTitle("Resource requested does not exist");
        problemDetail.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
        problemDetail.setProperty("dateTime", DateTimeUtils.currentDateTime());
        return problemDetail;
    }

}
```

(B) Without `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class WebRestControllerAdvice {

    //Ignore the two latest Parameters
    @ExceptionHandler({CienciaNotFoundException.class})
    ProblemDetail handlerMappingFor404(Exception ex, WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest req) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        problemDetail.setTitle("Resource requested does not exist");
        problemDetail.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
        problemDetail.setProperty("dateTime", DateTimeUtils.currentDateTime());
        return problemDetail;
    }

}
```

For both approaches, the `ProblemDetail` object created returns as expected (as the output shown above). Therefore:

**Question**

- Is mandatory extend the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class when `ProblemDetail` is applied?

Not sure if some special scenario is missing.

**Note**

According with my understanding: the [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) *abstract* class should be extended if need it to override any of the `handleXXX` methods for custom purposes. Correct me if this assumption is incorrect.